# Cannot resize partition Mac Os

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I removed a container disk 1, in order to allocate more space to Container Disk 2. but still cannot increase the size of container disk 1 which is 100G. my disk capacity is 251G.

Here is the detail of diskutil.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add the space from the deleted container to the existing container, the deleted container would at least have to physically reside after the existing container. In your case, this probably was not true. You can confirm this by viewing the output from the command given below.

```
diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Size -e Offset
```

Here, I assume the existing container has `disk0s3` as the identifier for the physical partition. If you restart your Mac, this will probably change to `disk0s2`. The offset should show the partition starts at around 151 GB. If so, then all the free space you created resides before the container and therefore can not be added to the container.

Apple's intent by creating APFS was for a computer to have only one APFS container. You can create additional volumes within a container and install more than one macOS operating system. If you had done this, then deleting the APFS volume(s) would have automatically made the free space available for other volumes.

Comment: Thanks @David for the answer, this is the result of the command:

diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Size -e Offset

Partition Offset:  151000186880 Bytes (36865280 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
Disk Size:    100.0 GB (99999985664 Bytes) (exactly 195312472 512-Byte-Units)
Device Block Size:  4096 Bytes

. Could you tell me how to remove the APFS ? and whether this operation remove the data or not ?